# Errors after namespace addition. Unable to access models

Tags: namespaces, laravel-4

I had to incorporate namespacing into my project because I need to use a model named 'Event', and so to avoid errors with the pre-defined 'Event' used by Laravel.

Composer.json:

```
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},

"psr-0": {
    "App": "app/models/"
    },
```

User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```

Directory structure pointing towards models:

models/app/User.php

Error on trying to 'sign-in' (This was working before the need for namespacing):

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class '\User' not found
```

Sign-in function:

```
public function postSignin(){
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {

    $title   = Auth::user()->title;
    $surname = Auth::user()->surname;
```

I have run the command 'composer dump-autload' after editing the composer.json file.

Any help would be hugely appreciated as to why this isn't working any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following `psr-0` then your directory structure of your models should be:

```
app/
    models/
        App/
            User.php
```

and try to set the model in config, go to: `app/config/auth.php`

change the model

`'model' => '\App\User'`

Good Luck !.

Comment: Even with psr-4 remembering to set the model in config/auth was helpful. Thanks